# Finding the derivative of a function.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Differentiate $$f(x) = \sin(\ln(\cos(x^2+1)))$$

My work: $u = \ln(\cos(x^2+1))$ so $f(x) = \sin u$ , $f'(x) = \cos u = \cos(\ln(\cos(x^2+1)))$.

I keep getting this answer, but where am I going wrong?

Comment: Why is it upvoted? Should not a person who asks a question to open any textbook and take a look?

Comment: When you substitute, do not forget to multiply by the derivative of what you substitute. That is the chain rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are forgetting to multiply by $u'$. $f'(x) = \cos(u) \cdot u'$. To compute the derivative of $$u = \ln(\cos(x^2+1))$$ We must use the chain rule once again. Now let $w = \cos(x^2+1)$ and keep continuing from here.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u = \ln(\cos(x^2+1))$ Then $f(x) = \sin u\Rightarrow f'(x)=\cos u$

Now $f'(x)=\frac{df}{du}\times \frac{du}{dx}$

To find $\frac{du}{dx}$:

$u = \ln(\cos(x^2+1))$,Let $v=cos(x^2+1)$ then you will have $u=\ln v\Rightarrow\frac{du}{dv}=\frac {1}{v}$

$\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{du}{dv}\times \frac{dv}{dx}$

To find $\frac{dv}{dx}$:

$v=\cos(x^2+1)$,Let $w=(x^2+1)\Rightarrow \frac{dw}{dx}=2x$
,$v=\cos w\Rightarrow \frac{dv}{dw}=-\sin w$

$\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{dv}{dw}\times \frac{dw}{dx}$

Can you finish from these Hints?

Answer (score 0):

It's $f'(x) = \frac{du}{dx} \times \cos u$..

Answer (score 0):

Notice, we have 
$$f(x)=\sin(\ln(\cos(x^2+1)))$$
Applying chain rule we get

$$\frac{df(x)}{dx}=\cos(\ln(\cos(x^2+1)))\frac{d}{dx}(\ln(\cos(x^2+1)))$$
$$=\cos(\ln(\cos(x^2+1)))\cdot \frac{1}{\cos(x^2+1)} \frac{d}{dx}(\cos(x^2+1))$$
$$=\cos(\ln(\cos(x^2+1)))\cdot \frac{1}{\cos(x^2+1)}\cdot (-\sin(x^2+1)) \frac{d}{dx}(x^2+1)$$

$$=\cos(\ln(\cos(x^2+1)))\cdot \frac{1}{\cos(x^2+1)}\cdot(-\sin(x^2+1))\cdot (2x)$$

Answer (score 0):

Your question is an example of a function containing several functions ([composite function](http://sydney.edu.au/stuserv/documents/maths_learning_centre/compositefunctionrule.pdf)) and so you need to use the chain rule a few times:

$$ f'(x) = \cos (\ln(\cos(x^2+1)))\frac{1}{\cos(x^2+1)}\times -\sin(x^2+1)\times 2x $$

$$ f'(x) = -2x\tan(x^2+1)\cos (\ln(\cos(x^2+1)))$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's define the following values, accompanied with their derivatives, below: $$\begin{align}u=&x^2+1,\ du=2xdx\\ v=&\cos(u), dv=-\sin(u)du\\ w=&\ln(v), dw=\frac{1}{v}dv\\ z=&\sin(w), dz=\cos(w)dw. \end{align} $$ Notice, the final function $z$ is $f(x)$ in a very condensed formed. Therefore, $$f'(x)= \cos(w)dw.$$ We then substitute everything back in. $$\begin{align}f'(x)=& \frac{\cos\big(\ln(v)\big)dv}{v}\\ =&\frac{\cos\big[\ln\big(\cos(u)\big)\big](-\sin(u))du}{\cos(x^2+1)}\\ =&\frac{\cos\big[\ln\big(\cos(x^2+1)\big)\big](-\sin(x^2+1))2x}{\cos(x^2+1)}.  \end{align} $$

Answer (score 0):

For a composition of functions you must apply the chain rule (thrice in this case)?. I'll do it in an informal, but illuminating style:
$$\newcommand\d{\mathrm d\mkern1.5mu}\begin{aligned}
\frac{\d\sin(\ln(\cos(x^2+1)))}{\d x}\hspace-6em\\&=\frac{\d\sin(\ln(\cos(x^2+1)))}{\d \ln(\cos(x^2+1))}\times\frac{\d \ln(\cos(x^2+1))}{\d \cos(x^2+1)}\times\frac{\d \cos(x^2+1)}{\d (x^2+1)}\times\frac{\d (x^2+1)}{\d x}\\
&=\cos(\ln(\cos(x^2+1)))\times\frac1{\cos(x^2+1)}\times-\sin(x^2+1)\times 2x\\&=-2x\tan(x^2+1)\cos(\ln(\cos(x^2+1))).
\end{aligned}$$